# How can I tell my Minecraft users which mods they need?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, server-administration

I'm hosting a Minecraft server that gets updated from time to time. I'd like to make it easy for players to know which mods they will need to play without requiring me to communicate with them outside of Minecraft. This info would be good for new players, as well as regular players who need to be informed that a new mod has been added to the server. Currently, if a player is missing a mod in their client, they will see a generic error message.

**Is there a way to inform users *in-game* which mods they will need?**

One idea I have is to put a web address on the game screen they see before joining, and then keep that web page updated, but that seems clunky. I know that players can be given the option to download Resource Packs, but as far as I know, this kind of this isn't available for mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Players can't join a server if they don't have all the correct mods installed (for Forge at least). I'd put a link in the MOTD, linking to a website like Pastebin, etc., and direct users there. Note that users cannot directly click links in the MOTD, so ideally it should be short.

Answer (score 1):

If your server has a landing page (e.g. [www.myserver.com/about.php/](http://www.myserver.com/about.php/)), then you could put a warning and links to the mods there. You could also distribute a "server launcher" (search on GitHub if this piques your interest) that automatically installs the mods, and Minecraft from a simple database, and then launches the player into the server. Or you could put a shortlink (bit.ly/whatever) in the MOTD. As Berrely said however, make it short, since links can't be clicked from here.

If you run a Bukkit/Spigot/Paper server, then this shouldn't be an issue, as Bukkit and their forks use server-side "plugins" rather than mods. However, it sounds like this isn't the case.

You could also change the welcome/onjoin message to link to the mods.

Answer (score -3):

On the server you have to install forge
next tell all your friends to get that forge VERSION on the PCs
finally just update the mods on the server "mods" folder and they should be able to join without the mods in "their" mods folder

Comment: Are you saying that if the players install the same version of Forge on their Minecraft client that the server is running, they won’t need to install the mods?

Comment: so if you install forge on your server, the players just have to install the same forge version. you only need to install the mods on the server. BUT make sure that the users have the SAME forge version.

Comment: This is (almost) completely false.  Your players need to install the mods into their modded mc install, just the same as you do on the server.  I say almost, because there exist server-side only mods that the client doesn't need, but those aren't nearly as common as ones that must be installed on both sides.

Comment: oh cuz i installed some mods on my server and just told my friends to get the same forge version. welp just follow what he said